# Filtering data based on a condition in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to count total objects based on a condition in django template. Lets suppose my model is below:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    election = models.ForeignKey(Election, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voting_booth = models.ForeignKey(Booth, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here i want total, votes based on each voting_booth. I can filter it in views but want to show all the votes with its respective booth.

Template is:

```
{% for v in vote %}
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
            <div class="dash-widget" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px lightblue;">
                <div class="dash-widget-info">
                    <h5>Total Voters:{{v.**???**.count}}</h5>
                    <h5>Voting Booth:{{v.voting_booth}}</h5>
                    <h5>Total Vote Earned:{{v.**???**.count}}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand well:

I would iterate `Voting Booth` instead `Votes`, and to get total voters do something like this before return the queryset of voting_booth to the template:

```
qs = Booth.objects.annotate(votes_count=Count("vote_set"))
```

then in the template:

```
{% for b in qs %}
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
            <div class="dash-widget" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px lightblue;">
                <div class="dash-widget-info">
                    <h5>Total Voters:{{ b.votes_count }}</h5>
                    <h5>Voting Booth:{{ b }}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, you can filter Count like this:

```
qs = Booth.objects.annotate(votes_count=Count("vote_set", filter=Q(vote_set__election__date__year=2021) & Q(vote_set__candidate__name="a name")))
```

Comment: But i don't have a vote foreign key in Booth model. Instead, the foreign key is in Vote model.

Comment: django automatically set a reverse relation when you have a `ForignKey` field, thats why I put `vote_set` inside Count

Comment: also you can change the name of reverse relation from `vote_set` to `votes` like this: `voting_booth = models.ForeignKey(Booth, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="votes")`, then change the query like this: `qs = Booth.objects.annotate(votes_count=Count("votes"))`

Comment: oo. Sorry for the silly question. Yes, there was a foreignkey in Vote model. Yes, it resolved now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, again. How can i get winners, whos got maximum votes per election and position??

Comment: I don't know where the position is, but to get winners you can do something like this:
`Election.objects.annotate(votes_count=Count("vote_set")).values("id", "votes_count", "vote__candidate")`

with that you will get an array of dicts with 3 keys and values: id of election, candidate and votes.

Comment: There is a Position model with fields election as foreign key and name only. So is this giving the who will win in which position?

Comment: theorically yes

Comment: It is giving total count of vote in that election. As below:

<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'position': 1, 'candidate': 2, 'votes_count': 5}, {'id': 1, 'position': 1, 'candidate': 3, 'votes_count': 5}, {'id': 1, 'position': 
2, 'candidate': 2, 'votes_count': 5}, {'id': 1, 'position': 2, 'candidate': 3, 'votes_count': 5}]>

Query used:

e = Election.objects.annotate(votes_count=Count("election_vote")).values("id", "position","votes_count", "candidate").filter(id=1)

Thanks